# Can't Input into a dynamic array with "double" data type

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having an issue with populating a `double` array, as I keep getting an error. Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to run:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    double d;
    double array_d[1000];
    cout << "You have chosen to use Double as your datatype\n";
    cout << "Enter the length of the array : \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nInput the array elements : \n";
    for (d = 0.0; d < n; d++)
        cin >> array_d[d];

    return 0;
}
```

error message:[Error] invalid types 'double [1000][double]' for array subscript

Comment: Is the error message something resembling `error: array subscript is not an integer`?

Comment: You should add some error checking to prevent the User from entering more than 1000 numbers.  Array overflow is not pretty.

Comment: sorry about that.. the error message is there now

Comment: @drewdormann Yes it does

Comment: @enthusiast that is your problem.  C++ does not define a way to index an array with a `double`.  Array indices are always integers.  They are counting whole things.  thing 0, thing 1, thing 2, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `for` loop to use integers:

```
for (unsigned int index = 0u; index < n; ++index)
{
    cin >> array_d[index];
}
```

The issue is that when `d == 0.3333`, `array_d[0.3333]` is kind of hard to address.  Array cells are singular and there is no definition of a partial cell in an array.

Also, get into the habit of using braces with all `for` loops.  The compiler will thank you.

Comment: the Array is supposed to have its data type as double so the values in the array should be doubles....

Comment: If you notice, there is a different between an array's **type** and the type for the **index**.  I did not mention the array's type, I've stated that the type for the **index** should be integral.  There's a difference between `array_d[6] = 3.14159;` and `array_d[6.534297] = 3.14159264;`.  Note that in your code, `d` is of type `double` and you are using it as the **index** into the array.  Again, what happens when `d == 0.1`?

Comment: Yes this works.. but the issue is that it allows the user to enter an integer value as one of the elements in the array but I don't want it to do that. Can you help?

Comment: So, do you want to prevent the User from entering 5.0?  What would be acceptable, 5.01, 5.001, 5.0001, 4.9999999999?

Comment: Exactly!! the user shouldnt be able to enter 5 yhh

Comment: You could compare the `floor` of the number or the `ceil` of the number to the original number (maybe even using `int` casting) .  If equal, tell the User to enter a non-integral number.